# How to hide audio file inside image

Tags: c#, image, byte, steganography

I'm working on a stenography program where i need to hide audio file inside image.
To implement that i need to CONVERT AUDIO FILE INTO BYTES[].

I thought of taking each byte and hide it inside each pixel of image. For that i would me needing some extra images to do so.
But the problem is that i don't know how to take the audio file and take each byte out of that. I have implemented the same with text file but i have no idea with the audio file.
Can anyone please help me with my doubts.

Comment: Is your problem that audio files are too big to hide in images, or that you don't know how to read the audio bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the bytes from an audio file doesn't differ from reading bytes of any other file:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myAudioFile.mp3");
```